# Need to convert scala Node into Elem

Tags: xml, scala

I have an xml RewriteRule and I'm trying to modify the passed Node `n`.  I want to do some things like copy & rename `n`, but those functions are only available on an Elem.

How do I convert Node `n` to an Enum?

Answer (score 0):

I expected to find an easier approach than this, but I ended up constructing a new Elem using the properties from the Node and that worked fine.

```
val wrapIndividualNodes = new RewriteRule {
  override def transform(n: Node): NodeSeq = {
    ...
    val nodesToRemove = "category"
->  val origElem = Elem(null, n.label, n.attributes, n.scope, false, n.child:_*)
    val editedElem = origElem.copy( child = origElem.child.filterNot(_.label == nodesToRemove))
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct an Elem from a Node as follows:

```
Elem.apply(node.prefix, node.label, node.attributes, node.scope, true, node.child :_*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're really looking at an Elem, rather than a Node - Node is a superset of Elem and includes other things such as whitespace for example - it doesn't make sense to treat whitespace as an Elem and I think you will get an exception if you try that.

But if you're guaranteed to get an Elem e.g. after pattern match, it is reasonable to use `node.asInstanceOf[Elem]`.